# elasticsearch not starting {0.90.0} : Startup Failed

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch, heap-size

I am not able to start elasticsearch. I tried

```
bin/elasticsearch

bin/elasticsearch -f

bin/elasticsearch -f ES_HEAP_SIZE=4g
```

but I keep getting the following message after a two-second pause...

```
{0.90.0}: Startup Failed ...
- OutOfMemoryError[unable to create new native thread]
```

NOTE 1: elasticsearch was working perfectly for me before I indexed 4 million documents into the server, after which I kept getting this error.

NOTE 2: even though elasticsearch does not startup, I am still able to execute the curl command on the elasticsearch server (strange indeed)

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Thumbelina",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.0",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

My guess is that one of the search queries to the 4 million documents is still running but I tried exiting the terminal, killing the process, increasing the heap size and stopping the elasticsearch process using bin/elasticsearch stop. My elasticsearch version is 0.90.0. Sorry for the long question and any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I finally was able to end the process using ps -aux command and then using the above command to increase the heap size. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This discussion](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/253) implies that increasing the `ulimit` value may help. Search for `ulimit` on [this Elasticsearch reference page](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/installation/) for additional details.

Does the process still appear to be running on the OS (e.g., using `ps` on the host box)?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I shall try increasing the ulimit value. Also, the process is not running on the host box (checked using ps), but I am still able to execute the curl command to contact ES.